# Java Spring MVC. Is this possible to overwrite singleton (or session) scoped bean by calling "new"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, javabeans

I'm learning Spring MVC framework by trying to create a simple but functional web page.

I'm wondering if it is possible to override a session bean by caling "new" operator...

I have created session scoped bean which refers to current user. If user is not logged, default bean will be used with guest parameters.

`<bean id="currentUser" class="pl.home.models.User" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>`

Then, in my controllers I have put below code:

`@Autowired @Qualifier("currentUser")
protected User user;`

And when user tries to log in, I would like to override instance of a user by calling:

`user = new User(email, password);`

Above code will overwrite user instance only "locally". Instance of a bean inside a Spring container will remain unchanged.

Is this possible to override user instance in a Spring container? Or maybe my aproach i completly wrong?

Thanks, Mariusz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically i solve it via Java EE `HttpSession` you can use the same approach. After user login sucessfully create a currentUser object and set it to `HttpSession` like below:

```
public void loginPost(HttpServletRequest request){
     //After sucessfull login
     User currentUser=initializeCurrentUser();
     HttpSession session=request.getSession();
     session.setAttribute(SessionToken.NAME, currentUser);
}
```

if it is not login initialize currentUser with default user setting and set to session. If you wonder clusterring you can save this currentUser to db and set recordId to session and query it when you need.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "**", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            Model model,
            HttpRequest request)` 


throws exception: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.HttpRequest]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: ok, it worked! Needed to add servlet-api to pom.xml and use HttpServletRequest, Thanks!